# How to check Velocity is animated

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

In jQuery we have:

```
.is(':animated')
```

But this doesn't work for velocity.js.

How to check the element is an animated?

Comment: Did you read the docs? Maybe this will help http://julian.com/research/velocity/#beginAndComplete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Velocity adds the class `velocity-animating` to elements that are being animated.

So you should be able to do it as follows:

```
.is('.velocity-animating')
```

See [here](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/blob/master/velocity.js#L1586)  and [here](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/blob/master/velocity.js#L3158) in the code.

Couldn't find it in the docs though I remember it was covered.